# Possible to save session state with 3 seperate files loaded in one session?

Tags: multiple-files

Alot of times I will have a vim session with three split windows with three different files. But something might come up where I need to switch projects, close the vim session, and come back to it later.

Is there a way to have it where I can save the state of that vim session with 3 seperate files loaded, close it, and come back to it later? With out having to vsplit each file manually again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out `:h Session'

You can save a session by `:mksession session_name.vim` and you can load a session by `:source session_name.vim` where `session_name.vim` is the name of the file that vim stores the info of a session.

If you use `:mksession` without a filename, it will by default be saved into a file called `Session.vim` in the current working directory.

You can configure what settings of the current session you want to be saved for later use by setting up `:h 'sessionoptions'`

Comment: Also check out Obsession by tpope on github—it makes some of the session stuff mindlessly easy.